# Apollo Client Cache vs Reactive Variables

Tags: apollo-client

Given the introduction of Reactive Variables in the new version of Apollo, the following question has arisen for me: does the use of the cache for local variables make sense any longer?
Instead of dealing with all the cache operations, we would only need to declare a Reactive Variable and include it in the fieldPolicy of a local variable in the `InMemoryCache()` initialization, in the read function of the respective field. When the reactive variable of a field changes, it triggers an update of the respective field. I do understand that the cache is extremely important when it comes to repetitive fetches , but in the context of local state management are there any use cases when you would still want to use the cache? Thank you!